# Proof that limits stay within the bounds

Tags: real-analysis

Prove the following theorem. Let $I$ be an open interval that contains the point $c$ and suppose that $f$ is a function that is defined on $I$ except possibly at the point $c$. If $m \le f(x) \le M$ for all $x \in I \setminus \{c\}$ and $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = L$, then $m \le L \le M$.

I've got this far but now I am stuck.

Assume that $m \leq f(x) \leq M$ for all $x \in I \setminus \{c\}$ and $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = L$.

We first prove $m \le L$. Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that $L < m$. This means there is some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $L + \varepsilon < m$. By the definition of a limit we know there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$ satisfying $|x−c| < \delta$ we have $|f(x)−L| < \varepsilon$. We can write the inequality as $−\varepsilon < f(x) − L < \varepsilon$. Which gives $f(x) < L+\varepsilon < m$. However this is a false by our hypothesis, therefore $m \le L$, as desired.

Now we prove $L \le M$. Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that $M < L$. This means there is some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $M + \varepsilon < L$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Now pick $x\in I$ so that $0\lt|x-c|\lt\delta$. Then you have $f(x)-L\le|f(x)-L|\lt\epsilon$. From $f(x)-L\lt\epsilon$ it follows that $f(x)\lt L+\epsilon\lt m$, contradicting the assumption that $m\le f(x)$ for all $x\in I\setminus\{c\}$. This proves that $m\le L$. Now prove $L\le M$ the same way.

We now prove $L\le M$. Suppse for the sake of contradiction that $L\gt M$. This means there is some $\epsilon\gt0$ such that $L-\epsilon\gt M$. By the definition of a limit we know there is a $\delta\gt0$ such that for all $x$ satisfying $0\lt|x-c|\lt\delta$ we have $|f(x)-L|\lt\epsilon$. Pick $x\in I$ so that $0\lt|x-c|\lt\delta$. Then $L-f(x)\lt|f(x)-L|\lt\epsilon$, so $f(x)\gt L-\epsilon\gt M$, contradicting the assumption that $f(x)\le M$ for all $x\in I\setminus\{c\}$.

Alternatively, it might be more efficient to prove the more general assertion: if $f(x)\le g(x)$ for all $x\in I$, and if $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)$ exist, then $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)\le\lim_{x\to c}g(x)$.

Comment: I have already proved that m ≤ L, im just not sure how i continue with L ≤ M.